# restler explorer prompt viewer with REQUEST_BODY json

Tags: php, documentation, explorer, restler

I am trying to properly comment my methods so that Restler's explorer will show the `REQUEST_BODY` for put and push values as my object's values. Right now all I see is `{ "property" : "" }`.

What I want is a json-formated string of the object I've created for this insert/update:

```
class Wash_Object extends \stdClass
{
    public $completed_date='';
    public $certificate_id=0;
    public $trailer_id=0;
    ...
}
```

I have been digging through the documentation for both Restler and Explorer but so far I have not seen exactly how you tell Explorer to fill in that text field under Value for `REQUEST_BODY`. What comment handles that little trick?

Answer (score 0):

You have to decorate the function with all the parameters you want populated in the field.  You don't necessary need to use the parameters if you're reading them from $request_data.

```
/**
 * Updates Item
 *
 * @url PUT /
 *
 * @param array $request_data
 * @param string $completed_date
 * @param int $certificate_id
 * @param int $trailer_id
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function put($request_data,
                       $completed_date,
                       $certificate_id,
                       $trailer_id)
```